# Definite Integral Summation Problem of function f(x)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, summation

**Question:**

[image: Problem]

**Note:**

*I came across a note from the help-section of mathematics stackexchange that it is "Ok to ask and Answer your own question" and so i was encouraged to post this question in Q&A style.*

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired. Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources. [As per this sensible post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20334/228113).

Comment: can you edit my question?I have no idea of LaTex.

Comment: No moment like now to learn.

Comment: ok I will try to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part_1:**

[image: Part 1 of solution]

**Part_2:**

[image: Part 2 of solution]

**Conclusion:**

*Any helpful addition to my post to emphasize the credibility of my answer would be gladly accepted.*